# decide / conclude / come to the conclusion

Tags: word-usage

Here's the context.

> The reason I quit my last job wasn't because it was bad or anything. In fact, what I do now is more or less the same. It's actually even harder(more difficult) in some ways and there are plenty of things that I miss about my old job. It's just that I had certain goals in mind and I decided that working there just wasn't in line with what I wanted to do going forward.

.

> 1. I ***decided*** that working there just wasn't in line with what I wanted to do going forward.
> 2. I ***concluded*** that working there just wasn't in line with what I wanted to do going forward.
> 3. I ***came to the conclusion*** that working there just wasn't in line with what I wanted to do going forward.

I feel they are different but I'm not sure what exactly the difference is.

Could you let me know the difference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little difference.

"Conclude" means at the end. So it implies "At the end of a thinking or after a logic process".  On the other hand you could "decide" quickly and based on your feelings or judgement.  "Came to a conclusion" is mostly a long way of saying "concluded" but suggests an even longer process.

> Three brothers each chose a sword.  The first decided to choose the one that looked nicest. The second investigated the balance of each sword and concluded that a Japanese katana was best.  The third discussed with his family and friends and came to the conclusion that fighting was wrong, so left to become a monk.

In the example you gave, you could use "decided" or "concluded" or even "cam to a conclusion"